# A font to override the High contrast setting

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, colors

I'm making an application that is related to colors. And hence, the color of the text should definitely be the one I'm setting. It works perfectly fine otherwise, but when the "High Contrast"  setting is turned on, the color vanishes and it is black and white. Is there a font that overrides this?

Note: I found a solution that detects if the setting is turned on. This way i can prompt the user to switch it off. But I only want to use that as a last resort.

Comment: Why would you assume that's a font setting, instead of a setting in your appication xml? just because you *see* it affecting your font, doesn't mean it's not affecting other things, too.

Comment: High contrast is a setting available in every android phone. I want a font that overrides it.

Comment: Yes, and have you looked up all the properties that "high contrast" changes? Because it doesn't change "the font", it changes a lot of things. So the most obvious thing is to read the docs and find out how you make you app tell Android that high contrast settings should be ignored for your app, not "set a font".

Comment: I just read that High contrast just changes the color of the text to black or white depending on the original color. Do you have any suggestions as to how to override this?

Comment: and where did you read that? Your post kind of needs the information to justify your assumptions, so that people can see you're not asking an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), and that you *know* what you need to do, just don't know how and can't find where. Right now it sounds like you want your app to run in "bypass any special modes", which would mean you're asking about a symptom, not the root cause, at the moment.

Comment: Here: https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6151855?hl=en

Comment: That's user documentation, which does not necessarily actually match what the SDK calls effect, so: did you read the SDK documentation for this feature as well?

Comment: Nope. Couldn't find any.

Comment: I understand why you find this frustrating but i did try searching for this issue online. Couldn't find it anywhere! stackoverflow is only my last resort.

Comment: that sounds unlikely, given that [google points to several places for you to ask questions exactly like these](https://developer.android.com/support.html), so I assume you've already done that. If not, SO was not your last resort =)

Comment: @Chirag did you find a solution for this? It seems that lots of Samsung devices after updating to Android Pie automatically switch on High Contrast text which is causing the color issues.

Comment: did anyone found any solution? This issue comes after API 27